# Drawable Images Not Re-Scaling on Tablets as Assumed

Tags: android, image, user-interface, drawable

I was reading on the Android documentation page for [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), and it states:

> "By default, Android scales your bitmap drawables (.png, .jpg, and .gif files) and Nine-Patch drawables (.9.png files) so that they render at the appropriate physical size on each device."
>
> ---
>
> "The system scales drawable resources to the appropriate size, based on the current screen density, if necessary."

Lately, we've been adding tablet-functionality to our application.  In landscape mode (and for portrait too, but I'll use landscape as an example), we have an image with text on the left side of the screen, and a button on the right.  Simple.  When developing this XML layout, I get this image (in the Graphical Layout part of Eclipse's XML editor) of what to expect when running the application on my 10" tablet:

[image: What I expect to see.]

However, when I run my application on my Acer Iconia A200, I get something more like this screenshot:

[image: What I end up seeing.]

In fact, the "image" you see in the 2nd screenshot looks almost identical, if not exactly identical, to the size of the image I see on our Android 2.2 MyTouch phone.

Thus, my question is, why would Android not be re-sizing the image as it shows in the graphical layout of the XML editor (like in the first screenshot?)

Things I've tried:

- I've added the drawable image, scaled appropriately, to each `drawable-_ _ _ _` folder.  Still, the image appeared the same.
- I've added the image to just ldpi, hoping it would scale up for a higher resolution tablet - it did not.
- I currently have that single image in the `drawable` folder (no extensions).  Still, the same behavior persists.

Any suggestions?

---

EDIT:

Code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/leftLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageViewLogo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@+string/logo"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_red" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutBelowImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center" >

        ... 4 TextViews here...

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the layout?

Comment: The code or the actual screenshot?

Comment: The XML layout - it's easier to see what's going on.

Comment: Well the 2 screenshots I supplied technically are the XML Layout - I just blurred out the contents.  As you can see, it emulates the image (in orange) just fine - but it shrinks a lot (to a phone-sized image) when running it on my actual tablet.

Comment: I disagree. Blindly though, if this is a nine-patch image, have you set it as a background? If not, is this a source image of an `ImageView`? In that case, have you set the correct `scaleType` and avoided the use of `wrap_content`?

Comment: I posted the code for the ImageView (it is a .png).  What should I use instead of `wrap_content`?  `Fill_parent` and `match_parent` make it fill the whole left side of my screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the **fit** `scaleType`s on your `ImageView`. In this case you may wish to use `fitCenter` to maintain the aspect ratio.

There are still some inconsistencies between the emulator and real devices.

To avoid using `wrap_content` yet maintaining the aspect ratio of the `ImageView` (with `fitCenter`), you can try a few things:

- Set it to `fill_parent`. Use weights in a `LinearLayout` (it is advisable to avoid nested weights but not critical).
- Set it to `fill_parent`. Make proper use of `layout_above` and `layout_below`.
- Create a custom view that extends `ImageView` and sets the correct aspect ratio in `OnMeasured`.
- Set a fixed width and height dp (the easiest).

Comment: `fitCenter` did not do the trick for the tablet.  It's still showing up small.  However, you said I should avoid `wrap_content` - what should I use instead then?

Comment: What about `centerInside`? About `wrap_content` what parent layout are you using?

Comment: Afraid not :(.. I've tried all the "center" possibilities and none of them worked.  Well, except for `center_crop` - that rescaled it to the right size but the image is indeed cropped (unless I can make it stay this size and not be cropped?)

Comment: You need to make the `ImageView` the right size, use weights in a `LinearLayout` or `layout_above` in a `RelativeLayout` combined with `fill_parent`/`match_parent`.

Comment: I can't use weights (I would have nested weights), and the RelativeLayout with `layout_above` and `fill_parent` on the image and the textfield-encapsulating-layout just makes them overlap.  I'll post that chunk of code.

Comment: Aha - nesting weights proved to be okay after all.  I let the ImageView take up 25% of the screen and the text for the rest of 75%, then used `fitCenter` as you suggested.  Thank you!